# Image not loading from custome-directory of public directory at Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, image

I am storing all of image at custom directory at laravel project root folder.

Custom directory means i have created new folder like "upload_files" at root directory.

whenever i am calling any files from this directory url be like "http://domainName.com/upload_files/folderName/fileName.jpg

But it's loading at web view.

Note : Image are loading from public directory. 

Here is my .htaccess file code below 

Note : I created new .htaccess file at root directory instead public folder .htaccess both file are exisiting at the project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
     RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1



   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ server.php

   </IfModule>

   # Deny index view Options -Indexes

   # Deny view a specific file <Files .env>    Order allow,deny    Deny from all </Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before these lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Try to add this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(upload_files)
```

This will allow access to upload_files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
     RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

     RewriteCond $1 !^(upload_files)

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1



     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ server.php

   </IfModule>

   # Deny index view Options -Indexes

   # Deny view a specific file <Files .env>    Order allow,deny    Deny from all </Files>
```

this should fix the problem

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

means all your request going to the public folder. so here are we are excluding the request for the `upload_files`

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(upload_files)
```